# ¿Como puedo hacer que una animación al ser infinita tenga un delay de x segundos?

Tags: jquery, css, css3, animación

Estoy utilizando la librería de animatecss para dar animación a mi sitio web, lo que necesito hacer es aplicar la animación `bounce` infinita pero que tenga un `delay` de `.2s`.

Para ello ocupe las clases que vienen para que la animacion sea infinita use `inifinite` y para hacer el delay use `delay-2s` pero solo al hacer la primera animacion se cumple el delay de 2 segundos, osea quiero decir que el delay no aplica para la animacion infinita.

```
<i class="material-icons animated infinite bounce delay-2s">mi_icono</i>
```

¿Como se debe hacer?

Comment: puedes colocar tu codigo de lo que has hecho hasta ahora , el css y el html

Comment: No sé como trabaja internamente la librería animatecss, pero si trabaja con keyframes y `delay-2s` se traduce en la propiedad css `animation-delay: 2s`, el delay solo se aplica al principio de la animación (en el primer loop por decirlo de alguna manera)

Comment: @andygibbs coloque la linea de código que tengo y a la cual quiero animar

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo si me pasa exactamente eso, solo en el primer loop funciona el delay. Gracias de todas formas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una de las cosas que puedes hacer es descargar el CSS de animate y editar el código para agregar unos frames que no hagan nada al inicio, ésta podría ser una solución sin usar Jquery.

Ahora, puedes también usar jquery y cada cierto tiempo activar y desactivar la clase 'animated' usando **toggleClass();**. Aquí está el ejemplo del código.

```
function re_animate() {
   $('.bounce').toggleClass('animated');
}
window.setInterval(re_animate, 2000);
```

Puedes agregar también una clase dummy o cambiarlo por un ID. Aquí tienes un [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/625901/) para que te hagas una idea.

Avísame qué tal te funciona eso!